# Alternative to signin without account

Tags: interaction-design, android, interface, login, mobile-application

I have a login screen, the user has two options:

**'Signin with Facebook'**

**'Continue without signin'** (no account registration required)

The button text for the second option I have chosen is:

**'Signin anonymously'**

As an account is still made automatically which will save settings etc for the users unique phone

I dont like this text though, does it sound strange?

should it be?

**'Continue without signin'**

**'Continue'**

Or something else?
Even so, these don't accurately describe that an account is being made automatically, hence why I did not choose them

Comment: How certain are you that automatically creating an account for them isn't in breach of privacy laws? Or by "creating an account automatically/regardless" do you mean "storing settings locally on the device"?

Comment: So how exactly this login works? No password required, no email, no social media account? Maybe I'm not right, but this would be strange no matter what name it has.

Comment: It would make an account number based on random generation that would be able the access account data remotely unique to that phone

Answer (score 3):

You can think of one more option in case you do not wish to register - but just expolre the app - that is **Skip button** on the login screen . this will allow your user to explore - be aware - like your app and then register at some key point . this will reduce your flying off visitors and make them stick for longer time span .
you can choose to place this skip button at the bottom side of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the label **"Use as Guest"**. That should make it clear that the next screen will be the same as the one when logging in ("Continue" can be ambiguous) and "guest", a relatively frequently used term, is easier to digest than "anonymous".

It still doesn't make it clear that an account is still made, but that sounds like a tall order for a button. If this is a privacy issue (if the data is saved only locally, it shouldn't be), consider adding a descriptive label below the button or showing a confirmation dialog after the user taps the button.

Comment: or just "Guest login"

Answer (score 1):

**"Sign in using your phone number"**

Or

**"Continue using your phone number"**

It's clear and exactly what is the case. Avoid ambiguous language if you want to be fair to users and make your intentions clear.

Comment: This makes sense if you require a phone number from the user, but if it's unnecessary info, then it doesn't make sense. (Also, remember that this app might run on a device that isn't associated with a phone number, like a tablet.)

Comment: As far as I understand it is a phone number required based on this part of the question: "As an account is still made automatically which will save settings etc for the users unique phone".